# jQuery find location.href and replace with function

Tags: jquery

I am turning all page elements from separate loads to Ajax pages if javascript is enabled using jQuery.  I have done most of thing, but one thing I need to check is for onclick/onchange events.

I have this:

```
    $("select").each(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('onchange')) {
            //CHECK FOR LOCATION.HREF
        }
        return false;
    });
```

and need to change things like:

```
location.href='/calendar-of-events/'+escape(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)+'/5/2011/
```

into:

```
pageload('/calendar-of-events/'+escape(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)+'/5/2011/')
```

How would I do that?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I tried:

```
    $("select").each(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('onchange')) {
            var ocval = $(this).attr('onchange');
            ocval = ocval.replace('location.href=','pageload(');
            ocval = ocval+')';
            $(this).attr('onchange',ocval);
        } 
        return false;
    });
```

but that doesn't work.  The onchange value is a function.

```
function onchange(event) {
    location.href = "/calendar-of-events/" + escape(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value) + "/5/2011/";
}
```

How would I change that?

Comment: You answered your own question, bravo!

Comment: I am looking for code to replace location.href and wrap the pageload function around the url.  The issue is that I need to make sure that there are no other functions within the onchange.  In this case I could just replace location.href= with pageload( and then add a ) at the end of the string, but if there are other things, I need to find the end of the location.href.

Comment: `return false;` in a `.each()` is the same as a `break;`.  If you are breaking after the 1st element, why not *only* select the first element?

Comment: in jQuery 1.6 your code works, but in 1.5 `$(this).attr('onchange')` returns a `function`, not a `string`.

Comment: Thanks Rocket, I overlooked that.  I want it to do all, I originally had it trying to overwrite the onchange, but that just made it do the location.href and what I had in onchange.  Will give 1.6 try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you don't use the `onchange` attribute, and just bind the event with jQuery.

```
$("select").change(function(){
   pageload("/calendar-of-events/"+escape($(this).val())+"/5/2011/");
});
```

If you can't do that, then I suggest you remove the `onchange` attribute, and rebind the event using jQuery.

```
$("select").each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('onchange')){
        // Get the onchange function
        var url = $(this).attr('onchange').toString()
            // Regex to extract the location.href
           .match(/location\.href\s?=\s?(['"].*['"])/);
        // If we found a match
        if(url !== null){
            this.onchange = null; // Remove onchange event
            $(this).change(function(){  // Rebind onchange
                // Eval the location.href string, setting "this" to the select element
                var urlstr = new Function('return '+url[1]).call(this);
                // Call pageload with our eval'd url
                pageload(urlstr);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/R6Zzb/10/

Comment: Thanks.  This is getting close to what I need.  The url returns a match in IE9, but FF4 it returns null.  Any idea why?

Comment: @fanfavorite: FF4 added a space before and after the equal sign in `location.href=`.  I fixed the code, should work in FF4 now.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript provides a whole bunch of string operations that can help you do this. For the example you've mentioned, a simple substr() will probably do. If it's anything more advanced, you might want to consider using a regular expression.

Here are a couple of tutorials to get you started:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: Thanks.  I use substr a lot in PHP, but unfortunately if you see the edit in my post, I don't know how to manipulate the initial function.  once I get the location.href value, I can recreate the function, and overwrite, but the proble is getting that value from within the function.